I hold an EU passport, but my spouse does not. How can she travel with me in Europe for more than 90 days?
I hold an EU passport, allowing me to stay and travel through Europe for more than 90 in 180 days. My spouse only holds a UK passport, allowing her to stay and travel only using the 90-day rule. How can she travel with me for an extended period? Can she get a travel visa?

For immigration purpose as in the linked comment: no problem. Then usual things apply: health insurance, registration to local authorities, taxes, etc. may apply but it depends on each countries. (health insurance depends on your wife residence)

In case it isn't clear, she doesn't need a visa, but things get more complicated if you stay in any one country for longer than three months.
